# Upload photo from Admin panel in Media folder with Django

Tags: python, django

I am using Django and trying to upload photo from admin panel in Media folder, but when I am saving the photo from admin panel, I give the error "[Errno 2] No such file or directory".

in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

in Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ... urls ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in Models.py

```
class sinfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField(default=0, upload_to='profile', null=True, blank=True)
```

Let me know how to save the photo from admin panel????

Comment: are you create media folder? if yes set perm to 777 and test. tel me result

Comment: Yes, the Media folder is in the project folder, How to change the perm??

Comment: sudo chmod 777 /path/to/media/folder

Comment: I have changed the perm to 777 on my server but it is not working like before!!! the error still is "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your media folder is exist in your settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
if not os.path.exists(MEDIA_ROOT):
    os.makedirs(MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this code create folder when folder not exist !